# Acumatica: How can I change the Reason drop down options in Cases?

Tags: customization, acumatica

I am trying to change the dropdown options for Reason and Severity in Cases. Does anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You change the values within the selector in a variety of ways, I would be mindful to update defaulting logic as well as paying close attention to how Acumatica responds to the current values in processing.

1. Extending PXStringListAttribute with additional values.
2. Replace Items within PXStringListAttribute with custom values.

https://riptutorial.com/acumatica/example/29102/modifying-marital-statuses

Comment: Reason is a special case, it uses custom attributes to set the list.

Comment: After further review it appears you are correct, I am currently working on the methodology to accomplish this but its proving....tricky.